# How can I use libc_nano with Clang?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, clang, libc

I'm exploring using clang as the compiler for ARM embedded development. As clang doesn't have an equivalent of `.spec` files, I'm having trouble convincing clang to link against `libc_nano`. How could I either tell clang to not link against any libraries by default so I can specify the correct library, or rewrite the `-lc` command to `-lc_nano`?

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
clang -target arm-none-eabi -mcpu=cortex-a5 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7-a main.c
```

Currently I get this error message:

```
/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin/ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc
```

EDIT: I've noticed that clang has a `-fno-autolink` which according to the help text: `Disable generation of linker directives for automatic library linking`. However it doesn't seem to do anything?

EDIT2: I'm aware I could abuse symlinks to achieve this. I would like to avoid symlinks in this case as it can make the build system brittle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon further google-fu and grep-fu, it turns out the answer was staring at me the entire time. Clang has a `-nodefaultlibs` that does the trick and prevents default linker directives. Although strangely it wasn't documented in `--help`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build fake libc.a without any functions inside and use it together with libc_nano.

Comment: That's not a terrible idea, although it doesn't integrate well into CMake toolchain files.